# External JPanle doesn't display on JFrame

Tags: java, mysql, swing, singleton

I'm doing a uni project. 
The project is a singleton swing app. I've maid a Mainframe where I'm trying to update every time the mainframe with a new external panel when the user clicks on a different menu tab. The problem is that when I load the external JPanel in the Mainframe doesn't display anything. I also ask if the way I'm taking is the correct one. Thanks!

Mainframe.js

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
JMenuBar menuBar;
JMenu homeshop, topCat, orders, login, register, exit;
ShopPanel shopPanel;
private OrderTrack orderTrack = new OrderTrack();

private void changePanel(JPanel panel) {
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().doLayout();
    update(getGraphics());
}

private class MenuAction implements ActionListener {
    private JPanel panel;
    private MenuAction(JPanel pnl) {
        this.panel = pnl;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        changePanel(panel);
    }
}
private void initMenu() {
    // Menu setup
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    //Items
    homeshop = new JMenu("Shop");
    menuBar.add(homeshop);

    topCat = new JMenu("Top Books");
    menuBar.add(topCat);

    orders = new JMenu("Orders");
    //orders.addActionListener(new MenuAction(orderTrack));
    menuBar.add(orders);

    login = new JMenu("Login");
    menuBar.add(login);

    register = new JMenu("Register");
    menuBar.add(register);

    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}
public void initMainFrame () {
    // Frame setup
    setSize(400, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    shopPanel = new ShopPanel();
    add(shopPanel);
    setVisible(true);
}
public MainFrame() {
    super("Welcome!");
    initMenu();
    initMainFrame();
}
```

}

ShopPanel.j

```
public class ShopPanel extends JPanel {
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private JList<String> shopList;
private ArrayList<String> titleBooks;

public ShopPanel() {

    // QUERY //
    DBQuery bookTitle = new DBQuery();
    titleBooks = bookTitle.QueryOne("select title from book", "title");

    // GRIDBAG LAYOUT //
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    // label //
    JLabel lblInsertOrderId = new JLabel("Insert order ID");
    panel.add(lblInsertOrderId);

    // LIST OF BOOKS //
    shopList = new JList(titleBooks.toArray());
    shopList.setVisibleRowCount(6);
    shopList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    panel.add(shopList);
}
```

}

App.js

```
public class App {

public static void main (String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainFrame();
        }
    }); 
}
```

}

There is no error message.

Comment: Why did you comment this line out? `orders.addActionListener(new MenuAction(orderTrack));` If you are trying to perform something when clicking on a menu item, you probably must register an action somehow.

Comment: You're ShopPanel class creates **2** JPanels when created, one, the panel variable which gets components added to it and which is **not displayed**, and the other, the class itself which gets no components added to it and which is added to to the GUI. Solution: don't create 2 JPanels where only one is needed

Comment: @Multicolaure it was by mistake :). I uncommented it and is still not working. i'm looking around to see if i can find something. Thanks for your answer! :).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks that was the problem! :)

Comment: Please change the title from JPanle to JPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ShopPanel itself IS a JPanel. No need to have a member JPanel and add everything to that one. That does not get displayed, because it does not get added to the whole component tree. Try removing "panel" and do everything without it, like: add() instead of panel.add(). Didn't try though...

Comment: Ty very much, it worked! Can i ask you if this is a good structure for this kind of project? and why if i press Order in the Jmenu doesn't switch the panel from OrderTrack?

Comment: create another question for that pls, I'm busy right now